# How to call a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to call a function every time my update was successful. The update is working my only concern is the alert pop-up every successful update.

```
    $.post(
        {
                url: 'update_question.php',
                data: 
                { 
                    id: id,
                    new_question: newText,
                },

                success: function()
                {
                    that.replaceWith("<section>"+newText+"</section>");

                    if(text != newText)
                    {
                        popup();
                    }

                }
        });

        var popup = function () {
        $(document).ready (function(){

        $("#myWish").click(function showAlert() {
            $("#success-alert").alert();
            $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
           $("#success-alert").alert('close');
            });   
        });
    });
    };
```

Comment: ` $(document).ready (function(){..` is invoked only once in the lifecycle of the web page...

Comment: @RayonDabre what should i do? remove?

Comment: @VanAdrianCabrera You can have something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v6tjtrtd/1/).

Comment: What should `popup()` do ?

Comment: Or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v6tjtrtd/2/)

Comment: How frequently your update will happen?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, My guess is `$("#myWish")` is added/removed dynamically...

Comment: @RayonDabre I think then we can do delegate, right? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3md85xg7/)

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't need to click on something to pop-up. I just want to call the pop-up every success update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var popup = function () {
       $("#success-alert").alert();
       $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
       $("#success-alert").alert('close');
     });   
   };
```

On the first update, pop-up showed but it doesn't show on the 2nd update

Answer (score 0):

> The `$(document).ready` jquery function waits until the DOM is loaded into your browser before it executes the javascript code contained within it's function scope {}.

So remove `$(document).ready` from your code.

Also note that single page applications only need to list `$(document).ready` once and all the listener events you setup are defined within it's body.

So you should have it listed somewhere at least once and then you define all your initial event listeners within its body.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll solve your issue

```
$.post(
    {
        url: 'update_question.php',
        data: 
        { 
            id: id,
            new_question: newText,
        },
        success: function()
        {
            that.replaceWith("<section>"+newText+"</section>");
            if(text != newText){
                popup();
            }
        }
    });

function popup() {
    $("#success-alert").alert();
    $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $("#success-alert").alert('close');  
    });
};
```

Comment: On the first update, pop-up showed but it doesn't show on the 2nd update